# How to set backgound in linechart of MP Chart library android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, mpandroidchart

I want to know is it possible to set background like this in MP chart library's Line chart like this, only in the graph area:

[image: Expected Graph Result]

I tried

```
lineChart.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext() , R.drawable.ic_graph)
```

but it applied background to the whole linechart with axis and everything.

[image]